# Encrypt (& decrypt) a number column in Oracle

Tags: oracle, encryption, plsql

1. How to do for encrypting  a number
   column in Oracle 11 (and also be able to decrypt them back) so that the same column stores crypted numbers along with (unencrypted ones (based on a boolean saved elsewhere)?
2. I actually did a function like this **that takes a number to produce a crypted number** and it worked fine in Oracle 10 but now it doesn't work anymore in ORACLE 11:

   ```
   function crypt (key varchar2, n number) return number
     raw_input RAW(128);
     encrypted_raw    RAW(2048);
     raw_key_ RAW(128) := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(CONVERT(key,'AL32UTF8','US7ASCII'));
   begin
     raw_input_    := UTL_RAW.cast_from_number (n);
     encrypted_raw := dbms_crypto.Encrypt(src => raw_input_, typ =>DBMS_CRYPTO.DES3_CBC_PKCS5, KEY=>raw_key_);
     return UTL_RAW.cast_to_number(encrypted_raw);
   end;
   ```

it throws this error with no explanations:

```
    ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
    ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_RAW", line 388
    ...
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to cast the encrypted raw to a number.  If I understand what you want this function to do, it seems you want to test that the input number = returned number (that you can encrypt and decrypt successfully).  If you wanted to just encrypt, you would return a raw, not a number.

Anyway, you should be casting the decrypted raw value to a number to test that the input number = returned number. Something like:

```
create or replace function test_crypt(k varchar2, n number) 
return number as
  raw_input_ RAW(128);
  encrypted_raw    RAW(2000);
  decrypted_raw      RAW (2000);
  raw_key_ RAW(128) := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(k);
begin
  raw_input_    := UTL_RAW.cast_from_number (n);
  encrypted_raw := dbms_crypto.Encrypt(src => raw_input_, typ =>DBMS_CRYPTO.DES3_CBC_PKCS5, KEY=>raw_key_);
  --return UTL_RAW.cast_to_number(encrypted_raw);

  -- use dbms_crypto to decrypt and return (hopefully same) number
  decrypted_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.DECRYPT
      (
         src => encrypted_raw,
         typ => DBMS_CRYPTO.DES3_CBC_PKCS5,
         key => raw_key_
      );

   return UTL_RAW.cast_to_number(decrypted_raw); 
end;
```

On my system anyway, the input number = returned number (key is from dbms_crypto.randombytes(32) ).  For example:

```
select test_crypt('50610FB89D98C7D906CB0A9917413221E4FE6FA62A9604302EE2C8F63E6BAD91', 234.21) from dual;
```

Output:

```
234.21
```

Comment: thats useless, why do i need to crypt and decrypt in the same function, just to get the same number? what would be the purpose of such a function? i want a crypt function to generate a crypted number to store and another independent decrypt function that would later take this encrypted number stored in a db and decrypt it in order to show it to the user

Comment: Like I said, it was unclear what you were trying to do.  If you want to encrypt a number (or string or whatever) you would return a RAW , not a number.  There is no "encrypted number", no such thing exists.  If you were a bit more polite, I'd probably take the time to break out my code above into 2 separate function (encrypt/decrypt), but its easy enough that I think even you can probably handle it.

Comment: i updated my question so its clearer now that i want to obtain a **number** not a raw...